# php system command with output and return code

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am looking for something in php that would given output (raw) of a system command in a variable along with the return code.

- [`exec`](http://php.net/exec) does this, but the output is in array and hence the data returned is not proper(as `\n` comes in new index).
- [`system`](http://php.net/system) outputs the data in the output stream and not in a variable.
- [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec) does not give the return value but gives raw data.

Comment: Can't you just [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the result from `exec()` to turn it into a string?

Comment: hey that worked...was stuck since a long time for this silly thing....thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for output buffering:

```
ob_start();
system($command, $returnCode);
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

This should preserve all white-space characters at the end of each output line (`exec` as you wrote destroys these, so `implode` would not be an option).

Alternatively, you can open a process and aquire the pipes (standard output, STDOUT) and read the output out of these. But it's more complicated (but gives you more options). See [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open).